# Codeigniter Session: www url shows old destroyed session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I have used unset($_SESSION['logged_in_user_data']) and it is destroying session successfully so when I try to load my site which is like below 
 exa: http://mydomain.in/folder/index.php
it will ask me to login as session is destroyed while logout but when I try to load my site with www means as below url:
www.mydomain.in/folder/index.php it shows old session which is already destroyed.

Comment: please read [ask]

Comment: It is obviously not destroyed, because session data doesn't just magically appear.

Comment: Session is destroying because if i use following url:
 http://mydomain.in/folder/index.php 
after logout than it shows blank session array.

Answer (score 0):

In config.php try this setting

```
 $config['cookie_domain'] = '.mydomain.in';
```

Comment: Any other alternative for this?